# How to show a array list into a picker?

Tags: arrays, append, rx-swift

Actually i am new in RxSwift. Please help regarding this matter.
 At first i am showing data into an array into a picker like this

```
func pharmacyList() -> Observable<[String]> {
        return Observable.just(AppSessionManager.shared.consultant?.pharmaciesArray.map({$0.name}) ?? [])
    }
```

now i just want to filter the array like

```
self.plannerSections.append(PlannerSection(header: pharmacy?.name ?? "", items: plannerData))
```

now i want to show this plannerSections array into a picker using rxswift?

Comment: please add more details and show some code.

Comment: Okay doing it sir

Comment: When i made the filtered array as func updatedPharmacyList() -> Observable<[Any]> {
        return Observable.just(self.plannerSections)
      
    
    }

Comment: then in viewcontroller it is showing in  viewModel.updatedPharmacyList()
                .bind(to: pharmacyPicker.rx.itemTitles) { _, item in
                    return item
                }
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)

Comment: it is showing Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> (@escaping (Int, _.Iterator.Element) -> String?) -> Disposable' to expected argument type '(Observable<[Any]>) -> (_) -> _'

Comment: @SuhitPatil please help sir

Answer (score 0):

Rx picker accepts array of arrays as input, so you need `Observable<[[String]]>`.